# EditText background color

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity that consists only of a huge EditText, full screen.

To match with my app's colours, i changed the background color of the EditText. But although it occupies the whole screen, it only changes the first line. Everytime i press enter i go to a new line and that line gets the background i want.

What propertie can i set in order to do this? I just can't see it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrap the EditText with a View and set the background color on the View.

Comment: Thanks for both answers, this is the simplest given i just want a background color.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the background of those Views that come with a background already, its better to provide your own image, and then use patch9 for proper resizing
I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

@everyone:

While searching for a solution for this same kind of problem i found this page. While reading the solutions i thought to myself: "There must be a better way to do this, instead of making your own styles and widgetborders, etcetera, etcetera, ....

Therefore, i present to you: the 1 LINE OF CODE SOLUTION!!! No trolling.

```
<your-widget-component-that-has-a-background-color>.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.<your-desired-color>, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);).
```

It works like this:

- "getBackground()" fetches the background from the component
- "setColorFilter" will call a filtering on the background image itself
- "Color." determines what color you want to pass onto the filter
- "PorterDuff.Mode." sets the kind of manipulation you would like to do with the given color and the fetched background image. People with knowledge of image editing software (GIMP, Photoshop, ...)  might recognise these modes. Basically, each mode has a certain effect on how the color is applied to the background image. to simply "override" the color of the image, while preservind it's gradients, borders and such, use "MULTIPLY"

I haven't profoundly read the PorterDuff class documentation, but honestly, ain't it a powerful bit of code?

With kind regards,

Comment: This works for me with Buttons (but the states look funny because the color filter multiplies against the blue Holo highlight or grey default state) but for some reason the exact same code isn't doing anything for my EditTexts.

Answer (score 0):

How to set the background color of an `EditText` widget:

```
editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```